# Python set timeout on Popen.stdout.readline

Tags: python, asynchronous, coroutine

I'd like to be able to set timeout on subprocess stdout and return an empty string if exceeded timeout.

Here's my attempt to do so using asyncio.

However, it failed on using `file.stdout.readline()` in `asyncio.wait_for`.

Any idea how to fix this ?

```
import threading
import select
import subprocess
import queue
import time
import asyncio

class collector():
    @staticmethod
    async def readline(file, timeout=3):
        try:
            line = await asyncio.wait_for(file.stdout.readline(), timeout)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return ""
        else:
            return line

    @staticmethod
    async def background(command):
        f = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

        while True:
            line = await collector.readline(file=f, timeout=3)



asyncio.run(collector.background("tail -f /tmp/2222"))
```

And here's callstack :

```
  File "/tmp/script.py", line 13, in readline
    line = await asyncio.wait_for(file.stdout.readline(), timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 462, in wait_for
    fut = ensure_future(fut, loop=loop)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 679, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

Comment: I don't understand what you expected to happen. ``file.stdout.readline()`` will return a line – a ``str`` or ``bytes``. You cannot wait for a ``str`` or ``bytes`` – you already have it.

Comment: Note that ``asyncio`` ships with its own [subprocess backend](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio-subprocess).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I've tried with the asyncio subprocess but it still didn't work out ... Perhaps you can show me some minimal example for how to do it right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `subprocess` library only provides synchronous functions. These cannot be directly used by `asyncio`, and manually wrapping them is inefficient.

`asyncio` already ships with [its own subprocess backend](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio-subprocess). Its [process representation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.asyncio.subprocess.Process) works similar to `subprocess.Popen` but allows to cooperatively wait for operations.

```py
import asyncio.subprocess

async def background(*command):
    # create subprocess via asyncio
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *command, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )
    while True:
        line = await readline(proc.stdout, timeout=0.01)
        print("read", len(line), "characters")

# read from an async stream vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv instead of a file-like object
async def readline(stream: asyncio.StreamReader, timeout: float):
    try:
        # stream.readline is a coroutine vvvvvvvvvvvv
        return await asyncio.wait_for(stream.readline(), timeout=timeout)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return ""


asyncio.run(background("cat", "/dev/random"))
```

Comment: This actually works great, thanks. However, if i put some more code after the `asyncio.run` line, it would never be called... Perhaps there's a way to run it in the background like when using threads ?

Comment: That's not really how ``asyncio`` works – it should always be run in the main thread. If you just want to run a single task in the background, use threads – ``async`` has no benefit unless you do *many* `async` things. Alternatively, have the event loop run your other code via ``asyncio.to_thread``.